# terminateAppHandler [base.js] Line 9357 Script

Tags: javascript, winjs, windows

I am developing a windows 8 application. After generating a page on the app (I copied the code from win js ([http://try.buildwinjs.com/#listview:gridlayout](http://try.buildwinjs.com/#listview%3agridlayout))) always an error occurs:

terminateAppHandler [base.js] Line 9357 Script

The code that generates this error is:

```
var terminateAppHandler = function (data) {
    debugger;
    MSApp.terminateApp(data);
};
```

I don't know what is meaning of the error it self, however with other pages which also use win js doenst happen.

Any idea why?

Comment: What's in the call stack at the time?

Comment: > terminateAppHandler [base.js] Line 9357 Script

Comment: It's just one line in the call stack?

Comment: > terminateAppHandler [base.js] Line 9357 Script
  Application_errorHandler [base.js] Line 9577 Script
  dispatchOne [base.js] Line 9427 Script
  dispatchEvent [base.js] Line 9427 Script
  drainOneEvent [base.js] Line 9469 Script
  drainQueue [base.js] Line 9486 Script
  Anonymous function [base.js] Line 2952 Script
  state_running.enter [base.js] Line 2951 Script
  _setState [base.js] Line 2667 Script
  Anonymous function [base.js] Line 2866 Script
  _execute [base.js] Line 2642 Script
  run [base.js] Line 3684 Script
  runner [base.js] Line 3835 Script
  [Async Call]

Comment: [External Code] 
  Anonymous function [default.js] Line 47 Script
  Global code [default.js] Line 3 Script

Comment: Looks like an error was handled. Why not hook that and see what the error is caused by?